# Writing an adjacent procedure for graphs in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am attempting to write a procedure that checks if 2 nodes in a graph are adjacent, or are neighbours.

I'm using SWI-prolog.

I am trying:

```
adjacent(X,Y,graph(_,E)):-
  member(e(X,Y), E).
```

However, this doesn't work and I'm confused as to why.

I'm using this as a test graph.

```
tem(graph([s,t,u,v], [e(a,b), e(b,d), e(b,c), e(c,d)])).
```

And I'm checking it on the repl like this:

```
?- tem(graph(_, E)), adjacent(a, b, E).
false.
```

But those 2 are both neighbours so it should return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat, the query that surprisingly **fails** is:

```
?- tem(graph(_, E)), adjacent(a, b, E).
false.
```

In Prolog, a good way to locate the exacte **cause** of such problems is to think declaratively and to systematically try suitable **generalizations** and **specializations** of your programs and goals.

For example, you can make the query above significantly *more general* by replacing `a` and `b` with the *variables* `A` and `B`, respectively:

```
?- tem(graph(_, E)), adjacent(A, B, E).
false.
```

So, this *still* fails! Therefore, in particular, any more specificy query will fail too, since the program is completely *pure* and *monotonic*, which makes such reasoning admissible.

Let us continue this and *generalize away* the single goal of `adjacent/2`.

Instead of:

```
adjacent(X,Y,graph(_,E)):-
    member(e(X,Y), E).
```

I now write:

```
adjacent(X,Y,graph(_,E)) :-
    true.
```

This of course makes the whole predicate significantly *more general*: In every case where the original predicate succeeds, this variant will succeed *too*!

Even with this significantly more general definition, we *still* have:

```
?- tem(graph(_, E)), adjacent(A, B, E).
false.
```

And now not much more remains to locate: The error must be in the *remaining* part, and ergo in the following fragment:

```
adjacent(X, Y, graph(_,E)) :- ...
```

If you look closely, it is this clause *head* that causes the failure: You are calling the predicate with a *list* as the third argument, but in this definition, the third argument is *not* a list.

This approach is called **declarative debugging**, and you will find more information under **[program-slicing](/questions/tagged/program-slicing)**. Prolog and logic programming languages in general are pretty unique for allowing the application of such powerful debugging techniques. Note that this approach can be easily *automated*: By simply asserting that this query *ought* to succeed, a program could have derived the fragment above and shown you the precise *cause* of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mat's excellent answer, the adjacent procedure is expecting the functor graph as the 3rd argument.

`tem(graph(_, E)), adjacent(a, b, E).` will pass in a list as the 3rd argument to `adjacent`, not the graph functor.

`tem(G), adjacent(a, q, G).` will pass in the graph functor as the 3rd argument, and not just part of the graph functor.

Comment: A good naming convention is to use variables that end with "s" to denote *lists*. For example: `graph(_, Es)`. This makes clearer that `Es` is a list. In contrast, when using `adjacent(a, q, G)`, I expect `G` to *not* be a list.